# Comparison of fit from OLS, GLS, GLM, ARIMA and DLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, arima, least-squares, dlm

I've been comparing the fit of OLS, GLS, GLM, ARIMA and DLM modelling approaches to my 20 observation time series data set. I had originally done so using RMSE, but wondered whether you could use AIC or whether the different type of model would render such pointless?

Any ideas much appreciated.....

Comment: You could use the normalised MSE to compare your models. It is described as the "ratio of mean square error to the variance of the series", comparing the results of your model vs a theoretical model that always predicts the mean of the data. This way, `nmse < 1` would make your result better than a mean prediction with `nmse = 0` a being perfect predictor. This should let you rank your models in terms of performance. (Source: [Iqbal et al., chapter 4.2](https://doi.org/10.1155/2019/4067135))